# How can I get dynamic content with a scheduled cloud flow trigger?

Tags: power-automate

I want to create a scheduled flow to export some items in my SharePoint list as a CSV file daily. When I use the "scheduled cloud flow" option to create it, though, I can't define a filter query to pull only the items I want:

[image]

It tells me there's no dynamic content available.

If I use exactly the same action (and same user) but choose a "when an item is created" trigger instead, then Flow does pull in my fields as dynamic content as expected:

[image]

So, the user is the same, the list is the same, the fields are the same... why in the world can't I see dynamic content when I use a timed trigger rather than a dynamic one? And what's the workaround... if I can't access any dynamic content with a scheduled cloud flow trigger, how do I build a flow that runs once per day with a dynamic trigger? I would create another flow to update a "Run Scheduled Flow" field each day, but then I'd need to be able to do that with a scheduled cloud trigger...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you cannot see the dynamic content is because it needs values from a previous step in your flow, and your only previous step (the Recurrence trigger) has no relevant values to use. In your other example, the "When an item is created" trigger has relevant values directly from SharePoint.

In order to provide a decent alternative, we'd really need to understand what you're hoping to achieve with your filter query.

**Update**

Based on your comment, I think the filter query for your first flow would need to be something like:

```
COVID%5Fx0020%5FTeam%5Fx0020%5F%5Fx002d%5F%5Fx eq 0
```

This assumes that the internal column name is definitely
COVID%5Fx0020%5FTeam%5Fx0020%5F%5Fx002d%5F%5Fx". The filter query doesn't seem to accept "true" or "false" but using 0 for false and 1 for true seems to work.

For your second flow, try this filter query:

```
Modified ge '@{addHours(utcNow(),-24)}' and Created lt  '@{addHours(utcNow(),-24)}'
```

Comment: I want to create a couple of similar flows - one that will check, once per day, for list items where the value of COVID%5Fx0020%5FTeam%5Fx0020%5F%5Fx002d%5F%5Fx is "No", export those items in a CSV, email that CSV to a hard-coded recipient, and set the value of the COVID%5Fx0020%5FTeam%5Fx0020%5F%5Fx002d%5F%5Fx field to "Yes". A second flow will check, once per day, for list items that have a modified date in the last 24 hours but a created date before the last 24 hours, and send an email with the values that have changed for each item to a hard-coded recipient.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some things to try

Comment: I expected that since the flow didn't seem able to access any dynamic information it would be unable to evaluate any filter conditions. I haven't built the second flow yet, but can confirm that even with the recurrence trigger, the filter condition can be evaluated as usual. Thanks!